# Using PythonQt wrap function that accepts custom class binded with pybind11

Tags: c++, pybind11, pythonqt

I have a C++ class `MyClass` that is binded to python using `pybind11`. Thus `MyClass` resides in python module named `mymodule`. That means from python I can do:

```py
import mymodule

my_class = mymodule.MyClass()
```

Also I have C++ class `YourClass`:

```cpp
class YourClass {
public:
  YourCPPObject() {}

  std::string foo(MyClass* myClass){ myClass->getName(); };
};
```

`YourClass` must be binded to python using `PythonQt` in the module named `yourmodule`. The problem is that the method `YourClass::foo(...)` expects the parameter `MyClass` that is binded using `pybind11` and it seems that `PythonQt` doesn't know anythng about `MyClass`. When I try to bind it using the code:

```cpp
#include <myclass.h>
#include <string>

#include "PythonQt.h"
#include <QApplication>

class YourClassDecorators : public QObject
{
  Q_OBJECT

public Q_SLOTS:
  YourClass * new_YourClass() { return new YourClass(); }  // constructor
  void delete_YourClass(YourClass* obj) { delete obj; }  // destructor

  // main function that accepts third party class binded with pybind11
  std::string foo(YourClass* yourClass, MyClass* myClass) { return yourClass->foo(myClass); }
};

int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
  QApplication qapp(argc, argv);

  PythonQt::init(PythonQt::IgnoreSiteModule | PythonQt::RedirectStdOut);

  PythonQt::self()->addDecorators(new YourClassDecorators());
  PythonQt::self()->registerCPPClass("MyClass","", "mymodule"); // I don't know maybe I don't need to register MyClass (still doesn't work)
  PythonQt::self()->registerCPPClass("YourClass","", "yourmodule");

  return qapp.exec();
}
```

I get an error in python:

```
ValueError: Called foo(MyClass myclass) -> std::string with wrong arguments: (<myclass.MyClass object at 0x7fc52eb92e68>,)
```

I can't find a way to tell to `PythonQt` that `MyClass` is already binded using `pybind11`.

If somebody has ideas please share.

Comment: I don't think mixing PythonQt and pybind11 is possible

Comment: @unddoch regarding to the scale from 0 to 10 how much would you rate your confidence? :) 
Depending on that probably I should stop working on that task...

Comment: Well - it's probably _possible_, but it's really not trivial. And unless someone has written such interoperability code and I haven't found it, you'll have to write it by yourself...